# How to get a list of all older posts without the newest one in Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working on a page template that should show the newest post on top and above it should appear a list with about 10 posts without the newest one.
The list with the older posts should only show the post title, the post date and the post category. Please see attached image below for clarification (sorry for the german language in the image but it is for a small local german sports newspaper).

[image]

The green border on the image shows the newest post. The content in the red border should show about 10 maybee more or less posts older than that one in the green border.
How can I reach this programmatically (with one loop or with two loops - don't know how it's possible) in my template file?

Thx a lot

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: You could run a typical loop and have a condition for the first post - displaying just the first post differently, while the older posts are displayed in that list format.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/applying-different-formatting-to-just-the-first-post-on-the-first-page

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/give-the-first-post-in-every-page-a-different-style

Comment: I have something tried with the wp function query_posts, but I think I am at the moment to stupid to understand how I can tell this function to not show the newest post also.
To get the table is not the issue... my issue is to only get all posts without the newest one. But, it could be, it is to early in the morning for my brain to work. ;)

Comment: I encourage you to go to the link from rnevius on the loop in WP, and read the whole page. https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: @TroyThompson to be honest, the page you have linked to is mostly a pile of crap. One of the worst pages in the codex. Needs proper editing and total removal of `query_posts`. Wish the core developers will remove `query_posts` someday like they have removed `extract()`

Comment: Just because the page may be garbage doesn't mean a beginner shouldn't read about what the loop is in WordPress. Yes, query_posts is awful, but the point was a beginner needs to know what the loop is.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Would you mind sharing a better resource for learning about the loop?

Comment: The two code examples from @JenisPatel and @mevius have solved my issue. I first used the Wordpress "default loop" like `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` as I switched to the "WP_Query loop" like `<?php $custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=-9'); // exclude category 9
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>` the issue was solved. Think it was a bit to early in the morning to solve some PHP issues in Wordpress, so I had some trouble with the loop(s). In the future, I take in mind there are more than one way to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this way :

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset'=> 1,);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

The important part in this code is `offset` and this magic word is doing the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the [entire loop for you](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), because that's an entirely different question. But to [query for the most recent posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you can do the following (which excludes the most recent single post by using the [`'offset'` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'offset' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I'm not going to complain about a down vote, but I'd at least like to know what I did wrong here, so that I can improve for the future. While not the only way to do things, my answer is one way to do it.